# Can I change how zsh autocomplete works?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I love the zsh autocompletion for navigating in files with commands like cd, but some commands have weird autocompletion, for example: when i type `snap ins`, bash autocompletes that to `snap install`, but zsh cycles between `snap Desktop`, `snap Music` and `snap snap` and then back to `snap ins`.

Other commands, like `apt ins` complete to `apt install` just fine, both in zsh and bash. Same with `apt install gedi` autocompletes and cycles tough further options just fine.

Is there any way that I can change the zsh autocompletion for commands to be more like bash? But still keep the cycling trough multiple options and menu style navigation.

Can I make bash autocompletion cycle trough options?

Comment: I think the behavior you're seeing means ZSH just doesn't know how to complete commands for snap (probably because nobody has written a completion function for it yet or you don't have that installed), so it just cycles through file/folder names.

Comment: Oh, cool, can i add these things myself? or can i make bash autocompletion  cycle trough options?

Comment: I found out how to make bash autocomplete closer to zsh autocomplete, just add this to .bashrc: 

bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
bind 'TAB:menu-complete'